# kernels to compute second order derivative of digital image

Tags: derivatives, image-processing

For an image $I$, its first order derivatives can be computed using several oprators, such as 
$$K_{sobel} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} -1 &0 &1 \\ -2 &0 &2 \\ -1 &0 &1 \end{array}\right]$$
$$I_{x} = I * K_{sobel},\ I_{y} = I * K_{sobel}.T$$.
And to compute the second order derivatives $(I_{xx}, I_{yy}, I_{xy})$, I can apply $K_{sobel}$ twice on $I$, however, I wonder are there any kernels which can be applied once to get the second order derivatives.

Here is what I tried, I made up 2 kernels,
$$K_{xx} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 &0 &0 \\ 2 &-4 &2 \\ 0 &0 &0 \end{array}\right]$$ 
$$K_{yy} = \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 0 &2 &0 \\ 0 &-4 &0 \\ 0 &2 &0 \end{array}\right]$$ 
and $I_{xx} = I * K_{xx},\ I_{yy} = I * K_{yy}$, they look pretty much the same as twice-applied-sobel results, but I failed to find a good kernel for $I_{xy}$, I need your help, any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convolution ($\star$) is associative, so if $I_{xx}=(I\star K_{\text{sobel}})\star K_{\text{sobel}}$, then $I_{xx}=I\star (K_{\text{sobel}}\star K_{\text{sobel}})$. This would mean that to get the kernel for $I_{xx}$ you just apply $K_{\text{sobel}}$ to itself. Practically, this means making a tiny image $I_K$ out of $K_{\text{sobel}}$, padding it with two rows of zeros all around, and then applying $K_{\text{sobel}}$ to $I_K$.

To get $I_{xy}$ you would just apply $K_{\text{sobel}}^T$ to $I_K$.

---

EDIT: Another thing that you can try is the discrete Laplace kernel:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -4 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

The one-d version looks basically like your kernels that you came up with:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks, I know that convolution is associative and I tried $K_{sobel}*K_{sobel}$, but it gives a kernel like this: $[[0,-8,0],[0,-12,0],[0,-8,0]]$, which is impossible for second-order derivative.

Comment: Good point. I would try the Laplace kernel, since that is supposed to approximate second derivative anyway.